# Is there some way to manage multiple domains content and layout through one single Laravel project?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, multiple-domains

I'm setting up a Laravel project and I want to manage content and layout of different domains through this project. I need to implement in a way how shopify works. You just need to point our naming servers and then you can manage content and layout of different domains. Is there any way in Laravel?

Comment: Are the different domains going to have the same routes? If so are they going to be specific domains or any number of domains that are going to be stored in a database?

Comment: It may have the same route where you can pass a dynamic parameter and have it vary. Also, any number of domains that will be stored in the database. Can we manage the content and layout of these domains through my Laravel project? @RossWilson

Comment: It might be worth having a look at: https://laravel-tenancy.com/